# PySpark: How to groupby with Or in columns

Tags: group-by, pyspark

I want to groupby in PySpark, but the value can appear in more than a columns, so if it appear in any of the selected column it will be grouped by.

For example, if I have this table in Pyspark:

[image]

I want to sum the visits and investments for each ID, so that the result would be:

[image]

Note that the ID1 was the sum of the rows 0,1,3 which have the ID1 in one of the first three columns [ID1 Visits = 500 + 100 + 200 = 800].
The ID2 was the sum of the rows 1,2, etc

OBS 1: For the sake of simplicity my example was a simple dataframe, but in real is a much larger df with a lot of rows and a lot of variables, and other operations, not just "sum".
This can't be worked on pandas, because is too large. Should be in PySpark

OBS2: For ilustration I printed in pandas the tables, but in real it is in the PySpark

I appreciate all the help and thank you very much in advance

Comment: there are just 3 columns, u can do a union and then sum group by

Comment: But then I will not have the desired outcome. If I do this would be the same as groupby by multiple columns. In this case, the result would be the same as the original dataframe, since there are not repeated combination, something like:
ID123 | sum(visits) | sum(investiments)
114 | 500 | 1000
213 | 100 | 200
532 | 200 | 400
134 | 200 | 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let's create our test dataframe.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = {
       "ID1": [1, 2, 5, 1],
       "ID2": [1, 1, 3, 3],
       "ID3": [4, 3, 2, 4],
       "Visits": [500, 100, 200, 200],
       "Investment": [1000, 200, 400, 200]
    }
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data))
>>> df.show()

+---+---+---+------+----------+
|ID1|ID2|ID3|Visits|Investment|
+---+---+---+------+----------+
|  1|  1|  4|   500|      1000|
|  2|  1|  3|   100|       200|
|  5|  3|  2|   200|       400|
|  1|  3|  4|   200|       200|
+---+---+---+------+----------+
```

Once we have DataFrame that we can operate on we have to define a function which will return list of unique IDs from columns `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3`.

```py
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

>>> @F.udf(returnType=ArrayType(IntegerType()))
... def ids_list(*cols):
...    return list(set(cols))
```

Now it's time to apply our `udf` on a DataFrame.

```py
>>> df = df.withColumn('ids', ids_list('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'))
>>> df.show()

+---+---+---+------+----------+---------+
|ID1|ID2|ID3|Visits|Investment|      ids|
+---+---+---+------+----------+---------+
|  1|  1|  4|   500|      1000|   [1, 4]|
|  2|  1|  3|   100|       200|[1, 2, 3]|
|  5|  3|  2|   200|       400|[2, 3, 5]|
|  1|  3|  4|   200|       200|[1, 3, 4]|
+---+---+---+------+----------+---------+
```

To make use of `ids` column we have to explode it into separate rows and drop `ids` column.

```py
>>> df = df.withColumn("ID", F.explode('ids')).drop('ids')
>>> df.show()

+---+---+---+------+----------+---+
|ID1|ID2|ID3|Visits|Investment| ID|
+---+---+---+------+----------+---+
|  1|  1|  4|   500|      1000|  1|
|  1|  1|  4|   500|      1000|  4|
|  2|  1|  3|   100|       200|  1|
|  2|  1|  3|   100|       200|  2|
|  2|  1|  3|   100|       200|  3|
|  5|  3|  2|   200|       400|  2|
|  5|  3|  2|   200|       400|  3|
|  5|  3|  2|   200|       400|  5|
|  1|  3|  4|   200|       200|  1|
|  1|  3|  4|   200|       200|  3|
|  1|  3|  4|   200|       200|  4|
+---+---+---+------+----------+---+
```

Finally we have to group our DataFrame by `ID` column and calculate sums. Final result is ordered by `ID`.

```py
>>> final_df = (
...    df.groupBy('ID')
...       .agg( F.sum('Visits'), F.sum('Investment') )
...       .orderBy('ID')
... )
>>> final_df.show()

+---+-----------+---------------+
| ID|sum(Visits)|sum(Investment)|
+---+-----------+---------------+
|  1|        800|           1400|
|  2|        300|            600|
|  3|        500|            800|
|  4|        700|           1200|
|  5|        200|            400|
+---+-----------+---------------+
```

I hope you make it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below:

1. Create `array` of all `id` columns- > `ids` column below
2. `explode` `ids` column
3. Now you will get duplicates, to avoid duplicate aggregation use `distinct`
4. Finally `groupBy` `ids` column and perform all your aggregations

***Note:*** : If your dataset can have exact duplicate rows then add one columns with `df.withColumn('uid', f.monotonically_increasing_id())` before creating array otherwise `distinct` will drop it.

**Example for your dataset:**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('ids', f.explode(f.array('id1','id2','id3'))).distinct().groupBy('ids').agg(f.sum('visits'), f.sum('investments')).orderBy('ids').show()
+---+-----------+----------------+
|ids|sum(visits)|sum(investments)|
+---+-----------+----------------+
|  1|        800|            1400|
|  2|        300|             600|
|  3|        500|             800|
|  4|        700|            1200|
|  5|        200|             400|
+---+-----------+----------------+
```